# calculate camera fov distance for sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

I trying to calculate the max distance the camera can zoom in on a sphere while still displaying all of the sphere on screen.

```
var dist =  diameter / (2 * Math.tan( camera.fov * (Math.PI/180) / 2 ));
```

this zooms in to much. The top and bottom of the sphere are clipped.
What am i doing wrong?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x98Fk/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sphere is being clipped for the same reason that if you stand close to a large sphere you can't see its "north pole".

You need to do the calculation for a plane that passes through the *front* of the sphere, not its center.

As a result, the quantity you calculated is the minimum distance to the *front* of the sphere. The minimum distance to its center is the quantity you calculated plus the sphere's radius.

(Note: this will yield a conservative approximation, due to the curvature of the sphere.)

EDIT: OK, here is the exact answer.

```
var dist =  radius / ( Math.sin( camera.fov * ( Math.PI / 180 ) / 2 ) );
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x98Fk/3/

The three.js camera field-of-view is the vertical FOV, so this this the result for the vertical direction. If the window is narrower than it is wide, then you have to deal with that issue.

Comment: if i calculate the minimum distance to its center, will that not make the camera zoom in more, resulting in increased clipping?

Comment: i updated the question with a jsfiddle example. if you click on the sphere it should zoom in using my calculation. could you please show me what u mean?

Comment: The calculation is exact for a cube: http://jsfiddle.net/x98Fk/2/. The curvature of a sphere makes the problem a geometric one. The smaller the FOV, the more accurate the approximation will be.

Comment: this actually works because the _sine_ calculates the hypotenuse of the triangle formed by the _tangent line_