# Fitting object to window by moving object

Tags: three.js

I want to fit my object to my output window. There are some answers that describe how to do this by moving the camera or changing the fov but for my use case, I want to do it by moving the object and leaving the camera at the origin.

Distance from camera to object is I think:

```
var dist = size / 2 / Math.tan(Math.PI * camera.fov / 360);
```

I think this is the distance from closest point on object to the camera so I mix in the radius of the sphere (in this example) to account for that.

I have tried to adapt the code in other answers but it is not working. Can anyone spot my mistake?

https://jsfiddle.net/m1rLzm12/

Comment: Perhaps this answer is helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500214/calculate-camera-fov-distance-for-sphere/22501791#22501791

Comment: Exactly what I needed - apologies for missing it the first time and many thanks.